# UnreachableBrowserException Chrome/Firefox Driver & Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I try to start a WebDriver with Selenium 3.14, 3.13 or 3.12 I get

"org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure." error.

I can run tests with older Selenium versions without an error. I have already set the Envirioment Variables (e.g. webdriver.chrome.driver). Also I have tried "System.setProperty" method. I use jdk8, maven 3.5.4 on IntelliJ.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this exception could be incompatible version of chromedriver.exe

Disable your chrome browser's auto updates, check its version and download compatible chromedriver and see if this works.